# set options in curl

Tags: payment-gateway

Currently I am developing a payment gateway and I have to generate a curl request to payment gateway.

Below is my normal php code of curl to which payment gateway approving my request because I have set CURLOPT_INTERFACE option to my server address on which my site is being hosted.

```
$url = 'https://mypaymentgatewayurl';


//url-ify the data for the POST
$requestQuery = '';
$requestQuery .= '&order_id=ordernumber';
$requestQuery .= '&api_key=myapi';
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestQuery);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'curl output : <br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

above php code is running without any problem and with desired output of approval.

Now problem starts here : I am not able to pass curl option in magento.

```
public function postBackCall($order_id,Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter = null) {
$configData = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/gateway');
$logFileName = 'gateway.log';
$logEnabled = $configData['debug'];
try {
    $apiUrl = $configData['api_url']; //i.e.https://mypaymentgatewayurl
    $requestQuery = '';
    $requestQuery .= '&order_id='.$order_id;
    $requestQuery .= '&api_key='.Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($configData['api_key']);
    $config = array('timeout' => 60,'verifypeer' => FALSE,'verifyhost' => FALSE);
    $httpAdapter->setConfig($config);
    $options = array('CURLOPT_INTERFACE' => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
    $httpAdapter->setOptions($options);
    $httpAdapter->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $apiUrl, '1.1', array(), $requestQuery);        
    $response = $httpAdapter->read();
    $httpAdapter->close();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
}
}
```

This is how my postbackcall method is being called from controller

```
$gatewaymodule->postBackCall($order_id,new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl());
```

Payment gateway is rejecting my request due to CURLOPT_INTERFACE is not being set as option. How can I set option in magento? What have I done wrong? TIA

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$httpAdapter->addOption(CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
```

or  as @Kamal mention remove quote from CURLOPT_INTERFACE int constant

```
$options = array(CURLOPT_INTERFACE => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
```

See /lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php

```
/**
 * Add additional option to cURL
 *
 * @param  int $option      the CURLOPT_* constants
 * @param  mixed $value
 * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
 */
public function addOption($option, $value)
{
    $this->_options[$option] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple quote can give you pain. A silly mistake on line

```
$options = array(CURLOPT_INTERFACE => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']); //see quote here
```

I hope this can be helpful to others.